Split a graph so each type of node is only appearing once in in each partition with as little cuts as possible
I have a table in BigQuery that represents the edges of a graph. Each node in the graph has a type. Each edge has a created_at property. Now I want to cut the graph into subcomponents. No subcomponent has more than one node of a selected type (A). I want to do this with as few edge cuts as possible. Prefer to cut younger edges rather than older ones.

What is an efficient way to do this?
Can this be done in SQL via recursion?
What is the type of algorithm that I need to use?

This is an example table structure.
No subcomponent has more than one node of type A in the resulting subcomponent.

Nodes:



node_id
node_type




1
A


2
B


3
A


4
C


5
A


6
B



Edges



edge_id
source_node
target_node
created_at
source_type
target_type




1
1
4
2024-05-01 20:43:00
A
C


2
2
6
2024-05-02 06:43:00
B
B


3
3
6
2024-05-03 08:43:00
A
B


4
6
4
2024-05-04 19:43:00
B
C


5
4
5
2024-05-05 21:43:00
C
A


reversed edges from above…







6
4
1
2024-05-01 20:43:00
C
A


7
6
2
2024-05-02 06:43:00
B
B


8
6
3
2024-05-03 08:43:00
B
A


9
4
6
2024-05-04 19:43:00
C
B


10
5
4
2024-05-05 21:43:00
A
C



This is what I currently do to get the component IDs. Where I'm currently stuck is how to cut these components into subcomponents.
with recursive
    connected_components as (
        select
            source_node as node_id,
            source_node as front,
            target_node,
            source_type,
            target_type,
            1 as depth,
            [source_node] as visited_nodes
        from edges
        union all
        select
            cc.node_id,
            e.source_node,
            e.target_node as front,
            e.source_type,
            e.target_type,
            cc.depth + 1 as depth,
            array_concat(cc.visited_nodes, [e.target_node]) as visited_nodes
        from edges as e
        inner join connected_components as cc on e.source_node = cc.target_node
        where cc.depth < 50 and not e.target_node in unnest(cc.visited_nodes)
    ),

    components as (
        select node_id, min(front) as component_id from connected_components group by 1
    )

select * from components

As a result, I would want to have a similar lookup table but as a lookup for the subcomponent ID per node.
If not possible via sql can be also solved via Python and then reimporting the lookup table for the components into Bigquery.
So with the data provided above, I would expect the following table:



id
component_id
component_id_from_pic (for reference only)




1
1
c2


4
1
c2


5
5
c1


6
2
c3


2
2
c3


3
2
c3




"I want to cut the components into subcomponents".  Perhaps you mean 'cut the GRAPH into subcomponents'?

"with as little edge cuts as possible."  I think you mean with 'as few'

"nodes of certain types only appear once in each subcomponent." better: No subcomponent has more than one node of a type

I suppose you could do an isolated breadth first search from each of the nodes of type A. Initialize your components to be singleton sets each containing a node of type A. Now expand these components by selecting edges to add to each component, similar to BFS. You can select these edges in reverse order of creation.
My attempt at this in Python is below.
First create the dataset (assuming you have means to pull this from BigQuery):
import pandas as pd

data = {'node_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'node_type':['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
        'attr_name': ['type', 'type', 'type', 'type', 'type', 'type']}

nodes = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'edge_id' : [1,2,3,4,5],
        'source': [1,2,3,6,4],
        'target': [4,6,6,4,5],
        'created_at': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'source_type': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
        'target_type': ['C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A']}

edges = pd.DataFrame(data)

Create a networkx Graph out of it:
import networkx as nx

attrs = dict()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(new_edges, 'source', 'target', edge_attr='created_at')
for i in range(len(nodes)):
  attrs[nodes.loc[i, 'node_id']] = {'type': nodes.loc[i, 'node_type']}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)


# in case G is disconnected to start with
connected_components = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(G)]
#Note: you can replace the above line with pre-defined components if you have

Then create the dictionary of <node_id: component_id> pairs:
import copy

given_type = 'A'

for component in connected_components:

  #Make an isolated component for each node of type <given_type>
  sub_components = [node for node in component.nodes if component.nodes[node]['type'] == given_type]
  comp_belong = dict((sub_components[i], i+1) for i in range(len(sub_components))) #This is a dictionary of the form <node_id: component_id>
  visited = [] 
  remaining_edges = []
  while len(comp_belong) < G.number_of_nodes():
    
    candidate_edges = set()

    cb = copy.deepcopy(comp_belong) #So that iterable does not change size in the for loop
    
    for node in [x for x in cb.keys() if x not in visited]:
        
        if node in visited:
          continue

        visited.append(node)

        for e in G.edges(node):
          if (e[0], e[1]) not in candidate_edges and (e[1], e[0]) not in candidate_edges: #select the edges connected to node, similar to breadth first search 
            candidate_edges.add(e)

        sorted_edges = sorted(candidate_edges, key = lambda edge: component.edges[edge]['created_at'], reverse =  True) #sort the edges by time, youngest first
        
        for selected_edge in sorted_edges:
          #identify whichever end point is not in the component dictionary and add it to the same component as its parent
          if selected_edge[0] in comp_belong.keys() and selected_edge[1] not in comp_belong.keys():
            comp_belong[selected_edge[1]] = comp_belong[selected_edge[0]]
            remaining_edges.append(selected_edge)
          elif selected_edge[0] not in comp_belong.keys() and selected_edge[1] in comp_belong.keys():
            comp_belong[selected_edge[0]] = comp_belong[selected_edge[1]]
            remaining_edges.append(selected_edge)
print(comp_belong) #this is your desired output, put it in a data frame or whatever data structure you need. 

Then remove the edges that are not in remaining_edges and visualize the graph:
G.remove_edges_from([e for e in G.edges if (e[0], e[1]) not in remaining_edges and (e[1], e[0]) not in remaining_edges])
nx.draw(G)

